# Concept of "equal" in C++20 concepts

Tags: c++, equality, c++20, c++-concepts

I have found multiple times, while reading some concepts definitions, the use of the term *equal*, like in `Swappable`:

> Let `t1` and `t2` be *equality-preserving* expressions that denote distinct *equal* objects of type `T`,

Is *equal* defined somewhere in the standard? I guess it means that the semantics of two objects, or the value they refer (the human semantics given to their represented domain value) are the same, even if the objects are not comparable (no `operator==` overloaded), or something abstract like that (like, two objects `a` and `b` are equal if `a == b` would yield true assuming it is a valid expression --for example, because `operator==` is not defined because it's not required).

Comment: It is about the human semantics given to their represented domain value IMO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since templates are going to work on the semantics the user gives, the concept of equality is largely defined by the program.  For example, if I am working with case insensitive strings, I can consider the strings `FoO` and `fOo` to be equal and `FoO` and `bAr` to be unequal.  The operations I supply must reflect this semantics.

Equality isn't defined based on `operator==`; on the contrary, `operator==` is (in a sense) defined based on equality.  [[concept.equalitycomparable]/equality_comparable](http://eel.is/c++draft/concept.equalitycomparable#itemdecl:2):

> ```
> template<class T>
>   concept equality_comparable = weakly-equality-comparable-with<T, T>;
> ```
>
> Let `a` and `b` be objects of type `T`. **`T` models
>   `equality_­comparable` only if `bool(a == b)` is `true` when `a` is
>   equal to `b`** ([concepts.equality]), and `false` otherwise.
>
> [ *Note:* The requirement that the expression `a == b` is
>   equality-preserving implies that `==` is transitive and symmetric.
>   — *end note*  ]